# Powershell script to logrotate logs

Tags: powershell

Ok.So I want to write a PowerShell script that simulates(sort of) the LogRotate option found in Linux.For one single file:no problem.But I want it to work for all the file INSIDE a folder.But...It doesn't work...at all.I tried doing it with foreach-object but it still doesn't work.I'm new to PowerShell programming,so you'll have to excuse me if my script doesn't look so clean.
Here it is:

```
function RotateLog {
    $log = "C:\Users\nvali\Desktop\scripts"
    Push-Location $log
    $target = Get-ChildItem $log -Filter "*.txt"
    $threshold = 300
    $datetime = Get-Date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"
    #$target_path =Get-ChildItem $log
    $filesize = $target.length/1MB
    $target | ForEach-Object {
        if ($filesize -ge $threshold) { 
            $filename = $_.name -replace $_.extension,"" 
            $newname = "${filename}_${datetime}.log_old"
            Rename-Item $_.fullname $newname
            $rotationmessage = ""
            Write-Host "Done" 
        }
        echo "$rotationmessage"
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `ForEach-Object` loop, `$target` needs to be replaced with `$_`

Comment: I edited the code.It still asks me for some parameters.Dunno why O.o

Comment: I corrected your formatting. `$target` is assigned a Get-ChildItem, the following `$target.length` will be the count of files not the accumulated file size. You'll have to compare the single file size inside the ForEach.

Comment: BTW no need to [reinvent the wheel](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Script-to-Roll-a96ec7d4)

Comment: @user6811411 references example code that was moved/taken offline when the [TechNet Gallery retired in Dec 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamblog/technet-gallery-retirement) but the new [Microsoft Archive on GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive) does not seem to hold this code either.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to check the file size of each file inside your foreach as [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) mentioned, and as [BenH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6788803/benh) commented, inside the foreach you need to use `$_` to access the current object that is being accessed.

This script worked for me without any errors.

```
function RotateLog {
$log = "C:\logDir"
$target = Get-ChildItem $log -Filter "*.txt"
$threshold = 30
$datetime = Get-Date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"
$target | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Length -ge $threshold) { 
        Write-Host "file named $($_.name) is bigger than $threshold KB"
        $newname = "$($_.BaseName)_${datetime}.log_old"
        Rename-Item $_.fullname $newname
        Write-Host "Done rotating file" 
    }
    else{
         Write-Host "file named $($_.name) is not bigger than $threshold KB"
    }
    Write-Host " "
}
```

Comment: This function works but if you filter on log and the new name still uses log you end up always appending the date on the previously rotated logs. For this reason I ended up using | where {$_.extension -in ".log"} to prevent this.

Comment: Very picky, but the naming of this function could be improved to follow PowerShell Verb-Noun naming convention. Other examples found around the web use [Invoke-LogRotation](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Communary.Logger/1.1/Content/Functions%5CInvoke-LogRotation.ps1) and [Reset-Log](https://gist.github.com/barsv/85c93b599a763206f47aec150fb41ca0). Also, if you look in these examples, you'll see support for keeping only the last X log files as well.